# Modelling actions in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am looking to standardize common actions using a design pattern but I am not sure which one is the best.

Let's say if we start off with two service Java classes with two operations/methods each.

```
class Service1 {
    public void performSomething() {
        // Some complex algorithm implemented here
    }
    public void performSomethingElse {
        // Some complex algorithm implemented here
    }
}

class Service2 {
    public void performSomething() {
        // Some complex algorithm implemented here
    }
    public void performSomethingElse {
        // Some complex algorithm implemented here
    }
}
```

Two services are sharing the same algorithms so naturally, I would want to refactor `performSomething()` and `performSomethingElse()`. My approach is to create two single-method classes for each refactored method.

```
interface Action {
    public void run();
}
class PerformSomething implements Action {
    public void run() {}
}
class PerformSomethingElse implements Action {
    public void run() {}
}

class Service1 {
    private PerformSomething algo1;
    private PerformSomethingElse algo2;

    public void businessUseCase1() {
        algo1.run();
        algo2.run();
    }

}
```

I feel like this simple approach is naive and I am very sure there's a more suitable design pattern that can represent an Action instead of creating a custom interface to present Actions.

Comment: Looks like the Strategy Pattern - there's plenty of documented examples in Java.

Comment: Actually I think this is quite common and not that farfetched. I think the design pattern that best describes this is the command pattern.

Comment: If you have methods performing the same thing on different types of classes, you would normally use generics, e.g. if you have a sorting algorithm, the algorithm itself does not need to know what it sorts. It only requires the objects to be comparable.

Answer (score 1):

With KISS and Spring in mind, I would just do the following:

```
@Service
class Service1 {
    public void performSomething() {
        // Some complex algorithm implemented here
    }
    public void performSomethingElse {
        // Some complex algorithm implemented here
    }
    public void businessUseCase1() {
        performSomething();
        performSomethingElse();
    }

}

@Service
class Service2 {
    @Autowired
    Service1 service1;

    public void performSomething() {
        // Some complex algorithm implemented here
    }
    public void performSomethingElse {
        // Some complex algorithm implemented here
    }
    public void businessUseCase1() {
        service1.performSomething();
        service1.performSomethingElse();
        // or
        service1.businessUseCase1();
    }

}
```

Comment: What if class Service2 uses performSomething() and performSomethingElse() also?

Comment: @user2176499 added to my answer

Comment: If you don’t want to couple them all, you can create a Service3 who is calling them with the same principal